# Add languanges to be always present on "Tools > Language > All Text" in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice

How do I explicitly add specific languages to "Tools > Language > All Text" in LibreOffice Writer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [ajlittoz](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/users/4669/ajlittoz/) [answered](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/247955/add-languanges-to-be-always-present-on-tools-language-all-text-in-writer/?answer=247973#post-id-247973):

> AFAIK, there is no way to make the UI dependent on custom configuration (I mean users may load additional language packs, every user having different need from another one).
>
> Since your question is about All Text, this means you intend to write a document in one of the cited languages. Even if you have a few paragraphs written differently, you basically end with a document in a dedicated language.
>
> My best advice is to create as many custom templates as you have main target languages: one for en_UK, one for es_SP, one for es_AR. The main difference between these template is in paragraph style Default Style Font tab where you set the language once for all.
>
> You can also customise the paragraph styles if cultural typographical rules differ with the languages. For example, in en_US, paragraphs have usually no first line indent while in other languages it is customary to have a first line indent. This difference can be recorded in Text Body.
>
> When you create a new document, you start from the appropriate template.

The solution seems to be adding templates.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the desired language extension (*.oxt file) from [here](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Language_support_of_LibreOffice)
2. After download right-click on this file and select open with `libreoffice`
3. Open `libreoffice` writer and open "Tools > Language > All Text" and select "more"
4. Now "Options- Language setting" will open. Here select desired language in "Locale Setting" tab and press apply. You are done.

Comment: Doesn't work if you want more than one language in the menu.

Comment: Yes when you select a specific language you will be able o see specific language. What you can do install different keyboard layout specific to the language. Whenever you will change the keyboard layout from panel shortcut LibreOffice automatically change to that language.

Comment: "Whenever you will change the keyboard layout from panel shortcut LibreOffice automatically change to that language." Why would I want LibreOffice to change language?

Comment: For the same purpose for which you want to add specific languages to "Tools > Language > All Text" in LibreOffice Writer. Here from panel I mean OS panel. Whenever you need to change from one language to another language within the document you can keep selecting different keyboard layout. that is the way.

Comment: That's a terrible solution.

Comment: This will further surprise you. What I am telling you was once reported as bug in LibreOffice.  Hence an option "ignore system input language" was added since LibreOffice v4.0. You can refer LibreOffice forums. What I can suggest you contact LibreOffice Forum and either request this "feature" or ask there.

Answer (score -2):

Install the corresponding package. For German, I used: `sudo apt install libreoffice-l10n-de` This will suggest more packages that might interest you. If the language is not available in LibreOffice, setting the environment variable `LANG` should help.

Comment: Will this add the language to the Tools - Language - All Text menu (and other entries). I think not. The question is how to add an installed language to these menus. Now, you need to select "More" to select them from the Options - Language settings dialog.

Comment: @vanadium Not it will not. "Now, you need to select "More" to select them from the Options - Language settings dialog" I dont think it allows you to select more than one.

Comment: After installation of your language package, you must restart LibreOffice. Then, the new language should be listed in "Tools > Language > For All Text'. @EmmanuelMess What language are you looking for?

Comment: @Sven It doesn't work. 3 languages, "English (UK)", "Spanish (Spain)" and "Spanish (Argentina)"

Comment: @Sven Installing "Spanish" to the system adds quite a few different regional language variations to the "Spelling... > Text language" menu, but none to the "Tools > Language > All Text" menu.

Comment: @vanadium To clarify my answer, selecting "More" doesn't let you configure the languages that appear in the menu, only the default language for texts, the language for the interface and such.

Comment: Confusing comment from your side as you are the one asking the question, not the one posting this answer. I agree fully with you that this answer will not add the language to the menu, so the answer is not valid. That is what my comment indicated.

Comment: @EmmanuelMess: You write about "Spanish (Argentina)" (that sounds like general locailization, not LibreOffice specific=. There is no such package for LibreOffice: there is only libreoffice-l10n-es. Did you install it via `sudo apt install libreoffice-l10n-es`?

Comment: @Sven No, I installed it via the "Settings > Language", one of the languages it adds (to the spelling menu) is "Spanish (Argentina)".

Comment: @EmmanuelMess The normal language configuration outside LibeOffice is unrelated to LibreOffice. As I wrote, you have to install packages for languages in LibreOffice.

Comment: @Sven The languages ARE installed, as I said I can find them in the "Tools > Spelling... > Language" dropdown menu.

Comment: @EmmanuelMess I see. Sorry, I have no more ideas. Is this a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 or an upgrade from an older version?

Comment: I was able to replicate the problem: I installed a language package I had never installed before (in my case, `sudo apt install libreoffice-l10n-es`). The language was not offered under "Tools > Language > For all Text".  This worked for me: set environment variable LANG in a suitable way in a terminal (for me: `LANG=es_ES.UTF-8`) and
 start `soffice` from this terminal.

Comment: "This worked for me: set environment variable LANG in a suitable way in a terminal (for me: LANG=es_ES.UTF-8) and start soffice from this terminal." Does this allow to set more than one language?

Comment: @EmmanuelMess, do you mean several languages for one document at the same time? If not: LibreOffice offered me several languages, e.g. the default language for my system and the specified Spanish.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108721/discussion-between-emmanuelmess-and-sven).